# Mismatch between jconsole shown Heap usage and Application calculated Usage percentage

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection, jvm, jconsole

We run a JVM application with 46 GB of Heap memory (44GB Old + 2GB Young).

We are connected to the jvm process using jconsole.

In the application we calculate the Used % of memory from the following code.

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
return Math.round( 100 * ( runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory() ) / runtime.getMaxMemory() );
```

When jconsole shows memory usage of 39 GB, the value given by above snippet is only 77% which is (0.77 * 46) 35.5 GB.

Why there is a mismatch there, How do i relate them? Am i missing something?
I need to find the usage % to trigger some action in our application.

Comment: Few queries: (a) Which Java version? (b) How do you ensure that both the application free memory calculation and jconsole memory report are done at the exact same time?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but still i am clear with it. Below are the answers for you
a) Java 7
b) I can monitor live through jconsole, from the application we print stats - I have observed this with loads of statical data.